# Apply a style on MultiAutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to apply a style on the MultiAutocompleteTextView but the style does not seem to be applied.

In style.xml I have following (showing just a portion):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButton</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/Edit</item>
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextView</item>
    <!-- In the line above I tried to set "android:multiAutoCompleteTextViewStyle" but that doesn't seem to work. My guess is that it is because MultiAutoCompleteTextView is a subclass of AutoCompleteTextView -->
</style>

...

<style name="AutoCompleteTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:completionHintView">@layout/completion_hint</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:ems">10</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">top</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
</style>`
```

And in my layout file I have following:

```
<MultiAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Since the theme is applied on the whole application, it should be applied to the MultiAutocompleteTextView as well. But when I try to execute the application I get the following error:

```
12-03 02:00:34.398: E/AndroidRuntime(591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #37: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you rewrite a theme or a style,you are only able to rewrite the specify attrs that the style declares.
layout_* attr not declared in Widget.AutoCompleteTextView,you should place layout_* for your specify view

Comment: Can you please post solution @gabga?  Thanks.

Comment: I've been away for a while so I haven't seen your comment until now. It's been a while since I was working on this, but if I find the code that I was working on, I will post the solution.