# Editing MultiAutocompleteTextView style

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, android-styles

## Similar questions

[Apply a style on MultiAutoCompleteTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675827/apply-a-style-on-multiautocompletetextview) : the issue was due to the fact that the OP was intenting to override some attributes the style didn't declare. This is not my problem.

[android: MultiAutoCompleteTextView style like gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35014640/android-multiautocompletetextview-style-like-gmail) : here, the OP wants to set the same style as GMail, and the answer shows 2 API. Moreover, no XML code is shown. Thus, it's very different from my question and expects.

## The problem

My **material** `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` style doesn't seem to be applied. More precisely, I just want to make the bottom default line of my (material!) widget become yellow and 1px of height. By default, it's gray and perhaps 3px of height, as you can see below.

[image]
(this is displayed when my activity's fragment starts, and this is the default material style of this `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`)

## What I have tried

A lot of things! :-)

1. I defined a style in my app's theme to override `android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle` (**NB: `android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle` doesn't exist**)
2. In the override, I tried to *a)* set colors - background color, color, accent color, colorControlNormal, colorFocusedHighlight, etc. etc. etc. - and *b)* set a background, defined in a XML file. **Nothing worked.**

### Sources

#### App's theme

```
<style name="" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/my_autoCompleteTextViewStyle</item>
    </style>
```

#### @style/my_autoCompleteTextViewStyle

```
<style name="my_autoCompleteTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_autocompletetextview</item>

    <item name="android:color">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:borderlessButtonStyle">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
</style>
```

#### @drawable/background_autocompletetextview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorRichYellow" />
</shape>
```

## My question

I don't understand why it doesn't work. I already did that for a `spinner` (select box), and it perfectly worked... How could I make it work for my material `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler
I think you need to add this line to your MultiAutoCompleteTextView

First of all, create a background resource for your MultiAutoCompleteTextView named "**underline.xml**"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/colorRichYellow" />
            <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

After that, simply set to your MultiAutoCompleteTextView item this:

```
android:background="@drawable/underline"
```

We need to do this, because you want resize the line too. If you only need to change the color of the bottom line, you can simply set

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorRichYellow"
```

avoiding create **underline.xml** file and without set **android:background** field

### UPDATE (as asked in comments)

If you want to use your style, please add this line to your style file:

```
<style name="my_autoCompleteTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
    ....
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/underline</item>
    ....
</style>
```

In this way, you can have this effect on all your ACEditText by setting your style!

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler Sure! Just add android:bacgkround field to your style/my_autoCompleteTextViewStyle instead of to the MACTextView.
After that set your personal style to the MACTextView and it's done

Comment: But is there any `<item>` way to do this?

Comment: @JarsOfJam-Scheduler i've update my answer, check it ;)

Comment: Thank you for help :-). However, as indicated in my question, it doesn't work. I have written: `<item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/autoCompleteTextViewStyle</item>` in my theme `<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`. I have also written `<style name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_edittextview</item>
    </style>` (`background_edittextview.xml` = `underline.xml`). It seems that using `item` way doesn't work (the other way does).

Comment: are you sure that you don't get mistake with words? In your comments you said you have <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/autoCompleteTextViewStyle</item>... but this is without sense. you need to setup YOUR style (my_autoCompleteTextViewStyle and not again the android style)